# How to retrieve form elements at controller in java

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to submit a form to controller in using java spring, in following code i am retrieving file element by following way successfully but not getting how to retrieve other elements(shortname and full name)value.
please help me out.

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 60px;">
        <form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" id="shortName" name="michael">
            <input type="hidden" id="fullName" name="michael jackson">
            Select file:
            <input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileAttachment"/><br/><br/>
                <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;">
                    <input style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="" onclick="uploadAttachment()" class="dialogbox" type="submit" value="Upload Report" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller side code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestPart("dataFile") MultipartFile file
             ){
System.out.println(file.getSize());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `@RequestParam String shortName` and `@RequestParam String fullName`?

Comment: yes, i did try your syntax but that dint help. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change the input elements and create the name attribute for both shortName and fullName like so :

```
<input type="hidden" id="shortNameId" name="shortName" value="michael">
<input type="hidden" id="fullNameId" name="fullName" value="michael jackson">
```

however you can remove the default value attribute and just enter the value yourself when the page render so value="michael" & value="michael jackson" are optional !

Then you can retrieve those input elements like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("shortName")String shortName, @RequestParam("fullName")String fullName
        @RequestPart("dataFile") MultipartFile file
         ){ .... }
```

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try something like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/your/url/{formParamenter}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String yourfunction(@PathVariable("formParameter") Type formParameter{}
```

The Type is the type of data, (String/int/float..etc).

In your case just change RequestPart to @PathVariable